# Are questions that ask why a certain snippet of code doesn't work in a browser alright?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I was thinking about posting a question on SO but I cannot tell if the question would be off topic or not. I haven't been able to find any specific rules or guidelines that address this specific sort of question either. The question is regarding a piece of JS code that works in Chrome, IE and other browsers but not in Firefox, instead it has very strange behaviour. Would it be alright for me to post such a question?

Comment: Yes, if the code does not work then it is a specific programming issue. But, before posting, you should do research yourself. Once you've gotten to a point where you cannot move forward, then you can post a question including all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue *in your question*. Also, include anything that you have tried already to fix this issue which didn't work.

Comment: @TinyGiant My main concern is that the question may be considered a "fix my code for me" type question.

Comment: Be sure to clearly explain what you expected, and how exactly which specific browser failed to do as you expected. That *might* mean including pictures, but *will* for certain mean including an MCVE.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, it is ok.

Indeed you need to provide smallest possible code (preferably as working [Code snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) ) that demonstrate the problem in the post with clear explanation what you expect and observe.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)/[CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/) would be nice *in addition* to code in the post as it lets people to clone/investigate in more familiar settings.

Comment: Why a JsFiddle when it can be a stack snippet?

Comment: @Deduplicator if code snippet is enough - sure, but with JavaScript it is rare to have problems with language itself - so JsFiddle, CodePen (or whatever ones favorite online snippet sharing service) could provide more complete demonstration involving CSS/elements (along with easy ability to clone and experiment).

Comment: Stack snippets are client-side runnable HTML+CSS+JS examples. Are you confusing them with code-blocks?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov see this blog post on SE creating stack snippets to replace jsfiddle as jsfiddle links could break: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I tend to include both a Stack Snippet and a JSFiddle link in my answers/questions, because it's a serious PITA to try and iterate over a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think my update captured your suggestion - if not - please consider editing the post to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is on topic.

Next to full code needed for reproduction, and clear explanation of problem - as we expect it for every question - your question on such an issue should include:

- description of the "weird" behaviour in one browser and the normal (expected?) behavior in the others
- the version of the non-working browser you're using, and the OS you're running
- that browser in the tags of your question

Also make sure to have disabled all plugins, extensions and whatever could interfere with the browser behaviour. Also relevant are any custom flags in the settings, especially FF can be messed up seriously via about:config.

If disabling those does solve the problem but you found it unexpected, state this as well.